Using Selection API to distinguish between start of line and end of line positions for the same index
The Selection API can be used to detect the cursor's position in a contenteditable container. However, if a cursor is placed at the very end of a line, or at the very beginning, I can not find a way to detect the difference as the index is the same. Even if I use the getBoundingClientRect() method on the range, it still returns the call bounding box for the two separate locations.
I have two screenshots showing the cursor in both positions and the details showing the same information


The snippet below can also demonstrate this


const updateRange = () => {
  const range = document.getSelection()?.getRangeAt(0);
  const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  let res = {
    startOffset: range.startOffset,
    endOffset: range.endOffset,
    top: rect.top,
    bottom: rect.bottom,
    left: rect.left,
    right: rect.right,
  };
  
  document.querySelector('code').textContent = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2);
};

const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('click', updateRange);
div.addEventListener('keyup', updateRange);
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
div {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 4rem;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

code {
  white-space: pre;
  float: right;
}
<main>
  <div contenteditable>CONTENT</div>
  <code></code>
</main>



I'm implementing a method to remove the entire visual line (deleteEntireSoftLine from here). Obviously this should behave differently depending on these two different scenarios.
I've tested this both on Brave/Chromium and Firefox. Both had the same functionality. Using getClientRects() performed the same as getBoundingClientRect().
I did notice that if I set the div to display: inline-block, I can no longer forcefully place the cursor at the clear end of the line, however I want the user to be able to place the cursor at the end of the line.
